# Using a where clause with join clause in Rails activerecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord

I want to do a join query with a where clause, but I'm getting a syntax error.

What is the correct syntax for using a where clause with a joins?

The [Rails docs](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#hash-conditions) gives an example using a hash with a single join, but can't find one similar to my problem.

**Query:**

```
User.joins("user_tags").joins("tags").where("tags.value <> 'single'")
```

**Error:**

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::SyntaxError: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "tags"
LINE 1: ...LECT "users".* FROM "users" user_tags tags...
```

Comment: Does your `User` have `user_tags` association?

Comment: Yes it does have it :)

Comment: Waah, should have been clearer: add associations to the question please.

Comment: If your relations are setup correctly, you should be able to just join like so
joins(:user_tags => :tags)

Comment: This will return one instance of User for every tag not equal to 'single' that is associated with the database record. Are you sure that that's what you want? You don't for example want Users returned where there is no "single" tag associated with them?

Answer (score 6):

You can define in your user model

```
has_many :user_tags
has_many :tags, through: :user_tags
```

and then just use

```
User.joins(:tags).where.not(tags: { value: 'single' })
```